# Javascript to Coffeescript push into foreach

Tags: javascript, loops, collections, coffeescript

I'm trying to find out how to transform this

```
  lastVoted ().forEach (function (voted) {
    voted.decision.forEach (function (decision) {
      var d = Decisions.findOne (decision.id);
      lastDecisionsVoted.push ({
        id: decision.id,
        title: d.title,
        choice: (decision.choice == 'red' ? d.red : d.blue),
        choiceclass: (decision.choice == 'red' ? 'text-danger' : 'text-info'),
        nochoice: (decision.choice == 'red' ? d.blue : d.red),
        nochoiceclass: (decision.choice == 'red' ? 'text-info' : 'text-danger')
      });
    });
  });
```

Into coffeescript... I've took a look to documentation and some answers here but I can not find the exact answer for my case, only a simple foreach loop...

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was more simple than I thought so here it is if someone is facing this same problem

```
lastVoted().forEach (voted) ->
    voted.decision.forEach (decision) ->
      d = Decisions.findOne(decision.id)
      lastDecisionsVoted.push
        id: decision.id
        title: d.title
        choice: ((if decision.choice is "red" then d.red else d.blue))
        choiceclass: ((if decision.choice is "red" then "text-danger" else "text-info"))
        nochoice: ((if decision.choice is "red" then d.blue else d.red))
        nochoiceclass: ((if decision.choice is "red" then "text-info" else "text-danger"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it as a list comprehension

```
decide = (voted)->
  getOne = (decision)->
    # method body here
  getOne(decision) for decision in voted.decision

decide(voted) for voted in lastVoted()
```

or you could do it sorta like this:

```
class VoteDecision
  constructor: ({@choice, @id, @title})->
    findItem()

  findItem: ->
    @item = Decisions.findOne(@id)

  toObj: ->
    id: @id
    title: @title
    choice: @choice()
    choiceclass: @choiceClass()
    # etc

  choice: ->
    if @choice == 'red' then @item.red else @item.blue

  choiceClass: ->
    if @choice is "red" then "text-danger" else "text-info"

decide = (voted)->
 lastDecisionsVoted.push(new VoteDecision(decision).to_obj for decision in voted.decision)

decide(voted) for voted in lastVoted()
```

(I did that by hand but it should be close to what you need)